# Different Rectangle Types of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is a way to obtain this kind of ''rectangle'' as node in tikzpicture? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close to you shape is `chamfered rectangle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {chamfered rectangle, minimum width=22mm, minimum height=11mm, draw}
                        ]
\node[chamfered rectangle corners=north west] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Description of ll options is described in TikZ/PGF manual, section *67.8 Miscellaneous Shapes*, page 733.

Comment: Node style is in MWE determined by `every node/.style = ...`. You can select instead it an appropriate name.